# jQuery AJAX POST - data doesn't get sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Configuration/AddServersAdvancedSelect",
    type: "POST",
    data: { selectedOUs: that.getByDataSelected() },
    async: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: result => {
        cont.setTabContentFromHtmlString(result, 1);
        cont.tabClicked($("td[data-value='1']").get(0));
    },
    error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) => {
        //
    }
});
```

EDIT: I came back to work today and it magically started working. I guess that's something

This is my ajax request towards the server. For some reason the data doesn't get selected. The getByDataSelected function works just like it should and reuturns good values. The Controller method has the name selectedOUs and everything matches. Does anybody have any idea as to why this ajax POST doesn't send data?

Comment: what kind of data are you sending?

Comment: that.getByDataSelected() ?

Comment: dataType: "html" ?  Should it not be JSON or something else?

Comment: @HaukurHaf The dataType can be XML, Html, script, json, jsonp, text or any combination of those.

Comment: What does that.getByDataSelected() do?

Comment: @BrettWeber, Yeah, I know.  In this scenario it should definitely not be HTML, I believe.

Comment: @HaukurHaf not sure, honestly. If the returned data isn't html that could potentially cause an issue.. I don't know that it is the reason for the request not transfering data, though

Answer (score 1):

jQuery defines the data parameter as

> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the
> server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
> It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to
> prevent this automatic processing.
>
> **Object must be Key/Value pairs**.
>
> If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
> based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

I'd be willing to bet that your return value of that.getByDataSelected() is not consistent with the expected parameter if it isn't getting sent.

In this case, your error function should be receiving an Internal Server Error [500]

Comment: I don't think that is the case. that.getByDataSelected() returns an array of strings. I've tested the array in every possible way. I serialized it to and checked if it has valid JSON sytax and it does. The biggest problem I have is that when I get an Internal Server Error it only shows me "/Configuration/AddServersAdvancedSelect" without the query string which is quite odd to me

Comment: POST verb submits a request body, not a query string, GET submits the data as a query string. If your method on the server is not expecting parameters and you are trying to read a query string, that probably is your issue. If that is the case, your method on the server will not even be reached because, technically, there is no method to receive the request you are sending due to the parameter requirements

Comment: Good observation though Brett, it is my current problem i think.  This post was helpful.